# Outlier query with mysql using group by

Tags: mysql

I use the query below to detect a 10 centimeter difference between the average snowlevel and the minimum snowlevel. But PhpMyadmin says it is an invalid use of the group function. Can't see what is wrong. Do you know it?

```
SELECT lud, res_id, resort, 
MIN(snow_valley) as snow_val_min, 
MAX(snow_valley) as snow_val_max,
ROUND(AVG(snow_mountain),0) as snow_mnt_avg, 
MIN(snow_mountain) as snow_mnt_min
from sv_condition_sw 
where (lud ='2011-12-31')  AND (AVG(snow_mountain)-MIN(snow_mountain)>10) GROUP by res_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every column in your select with group by must be either aggregated on, or included in group by. Conditions on aggregated expressions must appear in the having clause, like this:

```
SELECT lud, res_id, resort, 
MIN(snow_valley) as snow_val_min, 
MAX(snow_valley) as snow_val_max,
ROUND(AVG(snow_mountain),0) as snow_mnt_avg, 
MIN(snow_mountain) as snow_mnt_min
from sv_condition_sw 
where (lud ='2011-12-31')
GROUP by lud, res_id, resort
HAVING AVG(snow_mountain)-MIN(snow_mountain)>10
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the order of execution of an SQL query is `FROM` -> `WHERE` -> `GROUP BY` -> `HAVING` -> `SELECT` -> `ORDER BY`. So, the `AVG()` and `MIN()` you have in the `WHERE` are not evaluated until after the `GROUP BY`.

Use those conditions that have aggreagte functions in `HAVING`, not in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT lud, res_id, resort, 
    MIN(snow_valley) AS snow_val_min, 
    MAX(snow_valley) AS snow_val_max,
    ROUND(AVG(snow_mountain),0) AS snow_mnt_avg, 
    MIN(snow_mountain) AS snow_mnt_min
FROM sv_condition_sw 
WHERE (lud ='2011-12-31')  
GROUP by res_id
HAVING (AVG(snow_mountain)-MIN(snow_mountain)>10)
```